# Find command - file path with white space

Tags: bash, scripting, find

I'm trying to use a script that will run through a bunch of different folders and find Indesign files with "16x9" in the file name, and then loop them through a small AppleScript portion of code. I'm running into the problem where the result I receive is:

```
The file /Users/admin/Documents/00_Primary/Cordish/Cordish does not exist.
```

What I'm assuming is happening is that it's not accounting for the white space in the full file path. The full file path is this:

```
/Users/admin/Documents/00_Primary/Cordish/Cordish Horizontal/CordishAtlanta_Horizontal-16x9.indd
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=find /Users/admin/Documents/00_Primary -name "*16x9.indd" -print0
for f in `$FILES`; do

    open -a "Adobe InDesign CC 2018" "$f"
    osascript <<'EOF'
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Adobe InDesign CC 2018"
    set frontmost to true
    delay 5
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 15 using {option down}
        delay 2
        key code 15 using {control down}
        delay 2
        key code 48
        delay .3
        key code 125
        delay .3
        key code 48
        delay .3
        key code 25
        delay .3
        key code 36
        delay 1
        key code 36
        delay .3
        key code 1 using {command down}
        key code 2
        delay .5
        key code 36
        delay 1
        key code 13 using {command down}
    end tell
end tell

EOF


done
```

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need :

put the file processing in a `script.sh`, then :

```
find /Users/admin/Documents/00_Primary -name "*16x9.indd" -exec ./script.sh {} \;
```